# Access inherited class in a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, inheritance

I have a web service project that contains 3 classes:

- 1 Abstract public class (BaseClass.cs)
- and 2 public classes that inherit from it (InheritedClassA.cs and
  InheritedClassB.cs)

In my project (Test.csproj), I added a web reference to the above mentioned web service, and named it DAL.

When I'm trying to access for example "BaseClass" from my Test project, I write Test.DAL.BaseClass, and it recognizes it.

When I try to do the same thing to access any of my inherited classes (InheritedClassA and InheritedClassB) from my Test project it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the service to use the classes InheritedClassA and InheritedClassB either by returning instances of those classes in methods, or use [XmlInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) to include the unused classes in the reference. Make sure to update your web reference after you make any of these changes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using WCF for your web services?

If you're using `DataContractSerializer` (which you probably will be if you're using WCF), then you want to use the `KnownType` attribute to include types in the service description.

[Data Contract Known Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(InheritedClassA))]
[KnownType(typeof(InheritedClassB))]
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    // properties
}
```

Web-services are not really the same as WCF but I find that a lot of people use the terms interchangably.

Comment: you're mistaken. The term "web service" is generic. It includes ASMX web services, as well as WCF.

Comment: @JohnSaunders If I'm mistaken are you saying web-services *are* the same as WCF? Or is my answer incorrect in some other way? Was I wrong to include a disclaimer that the OP may not be using WCF?

Comment: Your statement "Web-services are not really the same as WCF" makes a false distinction.